# adding R package for installation from Github in Dockerfile

Tags: r, docker

How must I add installation instruction for a R package using github with my Dockerfile.

The usual command in R environment is:

```
devtools::install_github("smach/rmiscutils")
```

But no success so far. Tried to add github repo to installation instructions:

```
RUN install2.r --error \ 
    -r 'http://cran.rstudio.com' \
    -r 'http://github.com/smach/rmiscutils'
```

But I get an error:

```
error in download. Status was '404 Not found'
```

Maybe using vanilla R call but can't figure the command.
Any Hint?

Comment: Are you using the official R image from Docker Hub? https://hub.docker.com/_/r-base/

Comment: rocker/rstudio   a  r-server based one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
RUN installGithub.r smach/rmiscutils \
&& rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/
```

A good practice is to remove all downloaded packages to reduce image size.

Here added command when installing from Bioconductor (in case someone ends here searching for help)

```
RUN install2.r -r http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.0/bioc --deps TRUE \
    phyloseq \
    && rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/
```